# Find the number of ways the commander can be chosen

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Here is the question I'm trying to solve:

n soldiers standing in a line are divided into several non-empty units and then a commander is chosen for each unit. Count the number of ways this can be done.

My approach: Let $C(x)$ be the required generating function. Considering the type A structures on the non empty intervals as $a_k = 1$, the generating function is given as $A(x) = \sum_{k \geq 1} 1\cdot x^k$ which gives, $A(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$.

Next the type B structures are given by $b_k = {k\choose 1} $  giving the generating function $B(x) = \sum_{k \geq 1} {k\choose 1}\cdot x^k$ which gives, $B(x) = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$.

Now $C(x) = B(A(x))$

Solving for $C(x)$ I get

$C(x) = \frac{x \cdot (1-x)}{(1-2x)^2}$

Is my approach correct? How do I find the coefficient of $x^n$ in $C(x)$?

Edit: Any hints on where I'm going wrong here? Because the expected answer doesn't match the answer I have calculated. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the commander one of the soldiers in the unit?

Comment: Yes the commander is one of the soldiers in the unit.

Comment: It looks as if the coefficient from your generating function may be $a_n= (n+1)2^{n-2}$ at least for $n\ge 1$.  You can derive this from your generating function since its denominator suggests $a_n=4a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}$.   Manual calculation from your original question  confirms this starts $1,3,8,\ldots$

Comment: Thanks
Also is my approach correct? Because the expected answer is different.

Comment: @lettuce what is expected answer  ? For which value did you calculate ?

Comment: @lettuce By the way , the arrangements of soldiers in line  matters ?

Comment: The expression I calculated doesn't hold for n = 4, for example. The expected value is 21 but my expression gives 20. However, it matches the expected values till n = 3.

Comment: @Bulbasaur No the arrangement doesn't matter.

Comment: @lettuce in each unit , should the soldier and commander be different ? For example , for $n=4$  , if we divide them into $4$ unit , then each unit will have $1$ individual and everyone is both soldier and commander.

Comment: @lettuce moreover , the units are different or same ? For example  is $\{a,b\} , \{c,d\}$ different form $\{c,d\},\{a,b\}$ ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur For $n=2$ the three possibilities, with commanders shown in upper case, are $(A,b)$ and $(a,B)$ and $(A),(B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your generating function may be wrong.  In particular when $n=4$, I think it gives $20$ when I can count $21$ cases

I think if $b_{n,k}$ is the number of choices when you have $n$ soldiers and the first group has $k$ individuals then you can consider adding an additional soldier at the beginning so you can say $$b_{n+1,k+1}=\frac{k+1}{k}b_{n,k}$$ for $k\ge 1$ while $$b_{n+1,1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n b_{n,k}$$ which leads to results like

- $b_{n,k} = k\, b_{n+1-k,1}$
- $b_{n+1,1} = b_{n,1}+ \sum\limits_{m=1}^n b_{m,1}$
- $b_{n+1,1}=3b_{n,1}-b_{n-1,1}$
- sine the number you want $a_n = b_{n+1,1}$: $$a_{n,1}=3a_{n-1,1}-a_{n-2,1}$$

Since the numbers are $1,3,8,21,\ldots$ when $n=1,2,3,4,\ldots$, this leads to a generating function of the form $\dfrac{x}{1-3x+x^2}$ if you think the answer is $0$ when $n=0$, or of the form $\dfrac{1-2x+x^2}{1-3x+x^2}$ if you think the answer is $1$ when $n=0$.

This is a second order recurrence and can be solved related to $\frac{3 \pm \sqrt 5}2$ but can also be written by saying the coefficient of $x^n$ is $\text{Fib}(2n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand it now.

Comment: Could you please explain how you reached the listed results?

Comment: For example $b_{n,3}=\frac{3}{2}b_{n-1,2}$ and $b_{n-1,2}=\frac{2}{1}b_{n-1,1}$ so $b_{n,3}=3b_{n-2 ,1}$

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong , you said that " when i count $21$ cases " . So , i decided to count so as to reach same value but i could not . My procedure was  if $n=4$ ,then there are $4$ ways to divide it into non-empty sets such that $\{1-1-1-1\}$ , $\{1-3\}$ , $\{2-2\}$ , $\{2-1-1\}$ , we must also select a commander in each unit . I thought that we can calculate them such that $1$ ways for $\{1-1-1-1\}$  ,  $4 \times C(3,1)  =12$ for $\{1-3\}$ , $(6 \times 2 \times 2) / 2 = 12$ for  $\{2-2\}$ , $(6 \times 2 \times 2) / 2 = 12$ for $\{2-1-1\}$ , so $1+12+12+12 = 37$ . Wht  i missng ?

Comment: @ Your $\{1−1−1−1\} , \{1−3\} , \{2−2\} , \{2−1−1\}$ generate $1+3\times 2 + 2 ^2 + 2\times 3=17$ but you are missing $\{4\}$ with $4$ more possibilities making $21$

Comment: @Henry it does not make sense  , for example , for $\{2-2 \}$ , you wrote $2^2$ . It is the way for finding the number of commanders , but you did not calculate how to construct the units .There are $3$ ways to disperse $4$ different object into $2$ identical unit where each unit has $2$ object . Why did you not take them into account ? So , is it not $3 \times 2^2 =12$ ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur - the $n$ soldiers are "standing in a line" so there is only one way to divide into $2-2$

Comment: @Henry ohh , what a silly mistake :( , i forgot that information , thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

We use $$\frac{1}{(1-2x)^2}=1+2(2x)+3(2x)^2+....$$
Hence $$C(x)=(x-x^2)(1+2(2x)+3(2x)^2..)$$

So, coefficient of $x^n$ is $n.2^{n-1}-(n-1)2^{n-2}$.

Hence the answer is $(n+1)2^{n-2}$